# C# Access the Properties of a Generic Object

Tags: c#, generics, properties, types

I have a method that counts the number of Contacts each Supplier, Customer and Manufacturer has (this is a scenario to try make explaining easier!)

The models are all created by Linq to SQL classes. Each Supplier, Customer and Manufacturer may have one or more Contacts

```
public int CountContacts<TModel>(TModel entity) where TModel : class
{
    return entity.Contacts.Count();
}
```

The above of course doesnt work, because the 'entity' is generic and doesnt know whether it has the property 'Contacts'. Can someone help with how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way would be to attach an interface to the classes being implemented in the generic.

```
public int CountContacts<TModel>(TModel entity) where TModel : IContacts


interface IContacts
{
   IList<Contact> Contacts {get;} //list,Ilist,ienumerable
}
```

Comment: +1 Except you shouldn't return List<Contact> - preferably IList<> or maybe even IEnumerable<>

Comment: The problem with this is that LINQ to SQL classes use EntitySets for such a purpose, and the Contacts property with the type EntitySet will not implement the interface's property, so he'll have to implement it manually in every class.

Answer (score 3):

One way to impose a *contract* where Suppliers, Customers and Manufactors must contain a `Contacts` property is with interfaces. Make each entity implement one interface that contains the `Contacts` property:

```
interface IContactable
{
   IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts {get;}
}


public int CountContacts<TModel>(TModel entity) where TModel : class, IContactable
{
    return entity.Contacts.Count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers so far are correct but should also point out that the reason your code doesn't compile is because the TModel types don't have anything in common. By specifying a common base-class or interface they all implement with your 'Contacts' property your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create an interface just for counting. You can call it ICountable.

From [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vs2010ctpvbcs/thread/c1e4476d-8be8-41b3-9dae-55b834313ce6/)

```
public interface ICountable<out T>  
{
    int Count{ get; }
}
public class MyCollection : ICountable<string>, ICountable<FileStream>
{  
    int ICountable<string>.Count
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
    int ICountable<FileStream>.Count
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to the problem.

- Inherit the same abstract class or implement the same interface with the entities. (The others exhausted every possible solution with this.)
- If you are using .NET 4, the `dynamic` keyword may be the cheapest solution.

For example:

```
public int CountContacts(dynamic entity)
{
    return entity.Contacts.Count();
}
```

This means that `entity` will not be evaluated until runtime, and if you happen to call the method on an object that doesn't have a `Contacts` property, it will throw you an exception.